# Add integer array as key in uthash in c

Tags: c, hash, key, multikey, uthash

I came across `uthash`, a opensource library for hash table implementation in `c programming language`. I found it good and decided to use it in my project. Right now I am stuck with one issue .

I stared with small implementation where I created a hash table and I am trying to add `integer array as a key in the hash table`. Integer array is of size 26.  Below is my structure

```
struct record
{
  int key[26];
  UT_hash_handle hh;
};
```

When I am trying to add more than one entry in the hash table I am getting segmentation fault.

Below is my implementation

```
   struct record *hash_p = NULL, *op=NULL, *p=NULL;
   struct record find;

   //first entry
   hash_p = (struct record *)malloc(sizeof(struct record));
   memset(hash_p,0,sizeof(struct record));

   //filling some random index
   hash_p->key[0] = 2;
   hash_p->key[3] = 3;
   hash_p->key[7] = 7;
   HASH_ADD(hh, op, key, sizeof(int)*26, hash_p);

   //Adding second entry 
   hash_p = (struct record *)malloc(sizeof(struct record));
   memset(hash_p,0,sizeof(struct record));

   //filling some random index
   hash_p->key[0] = 2;
   hash_p->key[3] = 3;
   hash_p->key[7] = 8;
   HASH_ADD(hh, op, key, sizeof(int)*26, hash_p);

   //find the key in hash table
   memset(&find,0,sizeof(struct record));
   hash_p = NULL;
   find.key[0] = 2;
   find.key[3] = 3;
   find.key[7] = 7;
   HASH_FIND(hh, op, &find.key[0], sizeof(int)*26, hash_p);
   if (hash_p) printf("found\n"); else printf("Not found");
```

Am I adding second entry in correct way? How can I add multiple records in my above hash. Can anyone please help

Comment: Which line is giving you segfault?

Comment: And since that, by looking at the library, the macro is expanded quite few times, can you debug till the instruction that gives the segfault?

Comment: One thing that I see is different from the example is that when they call `HASH_ADD` the fourth parameter is `sizeof(record_key_t)` and you instead use the size of the array, not the whole struct. Does changing it to `sizeof(struct record)` makes any difference?